# Does SDL2 provide platform-agnostic means to keep a window from closing?

Tags: window, sdl, sdl-2

I understand that SDL2 raises `SDL_QUIT` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE` events (and use the former to break the app's render loop), but I don't understand how handling either event provides the ability to prevent the underlying window from closing (e.g. for user confirmation of exit).

Do I need to handle this per-platform?

Comment: I'm asking this with the hope that someone exposes some higher-level misunderstanding I have about SDL windows. The premise of this question seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the window from closing and application from terminating, you simply do nothing on receiving `SDL_QUIT` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see the problem now; I'm using native windows (i.e. `SDL_CreateWindowFrom`). I guess you have to make some sacrifices either way.